# Tensorflow concat two transfer learning model

Tags: tensorflow, concatenation, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning, image-classification

I want to concat two transfer learning models with the same input, the two model will run  parallelly , and then flatten the combined features for image classification. But I don't know why I got this error. Thank you!

```py
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(300,300,3))
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50V2
base_model2 = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input)
for layers in (base_model2.layers)[:90]:
  layers.trainable = False
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2
base_model1 = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input)
for layers in (base_model1.layers)[:90]:
  layers.trainable = False
output = Concatenate()([base_model1, base_model2] , axis= 1)
output = Flatten()(output)
output = Dropout(0.8)(output)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(output)
combine = Model(input = input, output = output)
```

Error Message:

[image]

I try to concat two transfer learning models, so I will have a model, input image, and have two transfer learning model for features extraction and run it parallelly and do the image classification

Comment: try `base_model1.output`, `base_model2.output` (assume they're same in shape).

Answer (score 0):

You want to concat the output of the models, that is `base_model1.output` and `base_model2.output`. They differ in the shape, so you have to flatten them before concatenating:

```
output = Concatenate()([Flatten()(base_model1.output), Flatten()(base_model2.output)])
output = Dropout(0.8)(output)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(output)
combine = Model(inputs = input, outputs = output)
```